# Scala flatmap signature definition

Tags: scala, definition

Maybe I don't understand some fundamentals, but what is the signature of `flatMap` in general? Let's imagine I'd like to implement type `T` supporting `for` expression, then I required `map`, `flatmap` and `withFilter` implemented by `T`. Is there any interface of something like that?

More precisely what is the source of the signature:

```
class T[+A] {

    def flatMap[B](f: (A) => T[B]): T[B]

}
```

Or is it a definition? May I implement `flatmap` with different signature?

Answer (score 8):

In general flatMap has signature:

```
class T[+A] {

def flatMap[B](f: (A) ⇒ T[B]): T[B]
def map[B](f: (A) ⇒ B): T[B]

}
```

For example for Option:

```
def flatMap[B](f: (A) ⇒ Option[B]): Option[B]
```

For Seq:

`def flatMap[B](f: (A) ⇒ Seq[B]): Seq[B]`

Of course in scala API you will see other signatures for Seq, List - because there is generic signature in trait `TraversableLike` for all collections.

For monad function map should:

```
m map f == m flatMap (x => unit(f(x)))
```

Where unit `unit(x) = single(x)`, for example:

- List is a monad with unit(x) = List(x)
- Set is monad with unit(x) = Set(x)
- Option is a monad with unit(x) = Some(x)

**Update**
There is no interface for flatMap/map. See example (copy to your REPL):

```
class C[+A](val a:A) { 
 def flatMap[B](f:(A) => C[B]):C[B] = f(a)
 def map[B](f:(A)=>B):B = f(a)
}
```

Then call in REPL for method:

```
scala> for { k<- new C(3)} yield {k}
res2: Int = 3
```

Comment: What is the source of above signature?

Comment: I've talked about def flatMap[B](f: (A) ⇒ T[B]): T[B] Where defined that signature(interface)?

Comment: @sh1ng Check out the Scala API; Option defines `flatMap`, and the page gives its signature as `final def flatMap[B](f: (A) => Option[B]): Option[B]` http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.Option

Comment: In the first code snippet, the return type of map is class T[A+] should be T[B] (rather than B), right?

Comment: Shouldn't the signature of `map` be `def map[B](f: (A) ⇒ B): T[B]` so that `def map[B](f: (A) ⇒ B): Seq[B]`?

Comment: Question aside: why is there no interface for `map`, `flatMap` and `filter`? Compatibility reasons?

Answer (score 1):

No special interface needed.
But if so you can implement [FilterMonadic[+A, +Repr]](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.generic.FilterMonadic) generic interface.

**Update**

SLS - ***6.19 For Comprehensions and For Loops.***

Methods: map, withFilter, flatMap, and foreach - can be implemented in different
ways for different carrier types. Code:

```
class A {
  def map(f: Int => Boolean): Boolean = f(10)
  def flatMap(f: Int => Boolean): Boolean = f(20)
}

for(x <- new A; y <- new A) yield x == y
```

And

```
class T[+A] {
  def flatMap[B](f: (A) ⇒ T[B]): T[B]
}
```

is not single way to define flatMap method.